# Was executable compiled with debugging info?

Tags: debugging, compilation

How can you check if a Linux executable was compiled with symbolic debugging info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quickest solution I can think of: Load it with GDB:

```
gdb myexecutable
```

You should get something like "(no debugging symbols found)" if there aren't any usable symbols inside.

Update: To return control to shell (or whatever) add `--batch`:

```
gdb myexecutable --batch
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, because I'm on OSX right now, but maybe file shows if it contains symbols or not.